# Filter function for streaming processor with contravariant input parameter compile error

Tags: scala, generics, covariance, contravariance

I am trying to implement the Stream transducer described in Functional Programming in Scala in chapter 15.
The authors do not use variance for the process type parameters `Process[I, O]`. However on the pursuit of really understanding variance, I added variance to the type parameters as such: `Process[-I, +O]`.
All was well until I tried implementing the `filter` function and got the following compile error:

`contravariant type I occurs in covariant position in type I => Boolean of value p`

This is the setup code that I have been working with:

```
 sealed trait Process[-I, +O] { self =>
    import Process._

    def apply(s: Stream[I]): Stream[O] = this match {
      case Halt => Stream()
      case Await(recv) =>
        s match {
          case h #:: t => recv(Some(h))(t)
          case xs      => recv(None)(xs)
        }
      case Emit(h, t) => h #:: t(s)
    }

    def filter(p: I => Boolean): Process[I, O] = self match {
      case Halt => Halt
      case Await(recv) =>
        Await {
          case Some(i) if (p(i)) => recv(Some(i))
          case _                 => recv(None)
        }
      case Emit(head, tail) => Emit(head, tail.filter(p))
    }
  }

  object Process {

    case class Emit[I, O](
        head: O,
        tail: Process[I, O] = Halt
    ) extends Process[I, O]

    case class Await[I, O](
        recv: Option[I] => Process[I, O]
    ) extends Process[I, O]

    case object Halt extends Process[Any, Nothing]
  }
```

I have already tried modifying `filter` signature to this:
`def filter[II >: I](p: I => Boolean): Process[II, O]`

Also tried changing `Await` to have the following type params:

```
case class Await[I, O, II >: I](
        recv: Option[I] => Process[II, O]
    ) extends Process[I, O]
```

But still did not manage to compile this code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
def filter[II <: I](p: II => Boolean): Process[II, O] = ...
```

with the original `Await`.

Comment: Yes, that worked. I think I tried that signature but with `Await` having `recv: Option[I] => Process[II, O]`